# Facebook javascript sdk is not woking

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code for facebook authentication.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '498085136....',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));

   //LOGIN FUNCTION 
   function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            alert('Success!');
        }else{
            alert('Login Failed!');
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
 }
  </script>
  <div onclick="login();">Login with Facebook</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know what's wrong with that code. When i check my error console, it shows FB is not defined..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make your html tag like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```